# Grails: Converting non domain class to JSON

Tags: json, grails

I'm attempting to convert my `Map<String, TableEntry>` to JSON in my controller as follows

```
def index() {
        // get tables
        JSON.use('deep')
        render(tables) as JSON
    }
```

My `TableEntry` is a non-domain class as I do not wish to persist it

```
class TableEntry {
    String teamName
    Integer gamesPlayed = 0
    Integer gamesWon = 0
    Integer gamesDrawn = 0
    Integer gamesLost = 0
    Integer points = 0

    // other methods
```

However, when my JSON is rendered in the client, I get the following:

```
'Team A':TableEntry@3b52fb28, 'Team Z':TableEntry@44e71d85
```

How do I get this to convert fully?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your render statement is incorrect. You have:

```
    render(tables) as JSON
```

However, it should read:

```
    render tables as JSON
```

By wrapping the variable "tables" in parenthesis, the render is happening before you can cast "tables" to JSON.

Comment: I've had problems with that syntax too, depending on the expression complexity, so I usually use `render(tables as JSON)` to make sure `as` is applied correctly